# which statement in R

Tags: r, function

I have a data set consisting of two columns of numbers: **column "dd"** and **column "yy"** (**import my data set to your Rstudio Below**).

I'm trying to understand what is **"yy"** when **"dd"** is exactly **"0" ?**

I'm using the following `which()` statement: `yy[which(dd==0)]` but this code doesn't work?

Here is my **data for your examination:**

```
id <- "0B5V8AyEFBTmXM1VIYUYxSG5tSjQ"

Data <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))

dd <- Data[,1]
yy <- Data[,2]
```

Comment: is use of `which` function requirement?

Comment: I assume `dd` is a column in your data frame. It did not work, because you are accessing `dd` as a variable. You either have to extract `dd` column or create a separate environment for your data frame columns that can be accessed as a variable. `with` creates a separate environment for your data.

Comment: Also you have to put a `,` comma if it a data frame. Like this `with( yy, yy[ which( dd==0 ),  ])`

Comment: Try `yy[isTRUE(all.equal(dd, 0))]` instead of `yy[dd == 0]`. Forget about `which()`, it isn't needed here. If you really want to use `which()`, you can try `yy[which(isTRUE(all.equal(dd, 0)))]`, but it is not good style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(1:4, 0))
with(df1,  df1[ b == 0, ])
#   a b
# 5 5 0
```

or using `which`

```
with(df1,  df1[ which( b == 0 ), ])
```

Comment: so, why `which` the way I used it above didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: `which` works too

```
> df1 <- data.frame(a = c(0,0,0,1,2), b = c(1:4, 0))
> dd <- df1[,1]
> yy <- df1[,2]
> dd
[1] 0 0 0 1 2
> yy
[1] 1 2 3 4 0
> yy[which(dd==0)]
[1] 1 2 3
```

The below solution is without using `which` statement. I hope that's not a requirement. `x` is a vector which will contain values of `yy` where `dd` is `0`. You can add below your existing code.

```
x <- Data$yy[Data$dd==0]
print(x)
```